# Passport.js Strategies Comparison

Tags: node.js, angular, express, authentication, passport.js

I am confused about what Passport.js strategies to use in my web app made with:
Node.JS
Express
Angular

What are the differences between: 
Passport-local,
Passport-http-bearer,
Passport-jwt?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the difference is authorization strategy use choose, nothing else. passport js will work same way for each of them. the simplest one is passport-local strategy